# How is the pid (process id) allocated for a daemon process in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I researched the Linux kernel code (2.6.11) about the creation of a process/thread, and followed do_fork()->alloc_pidmap()

It seems that alloc_pidmap always returns pid > 300 once the previous pid's ever reached the max pid, while actually daemon's pid is always < 300 (Is this correct?).

Does a daemon obtain its pid using a function other than alloc_pidmap()? If so, does it imply the daemon process is not created using do_fork?

Comment: 2.6.11 is a very old kernel. Current one is 3.1! And why do you ask??

Comment: I want to learn about the procedure of the process creation. The old version doesn't matter much. I am wondering if a daemon process is created very late, how does kernel ensure that it obtains a pid < 300. Or my impression that a daemon's pid < 300 is incorrect?

Comment: The code for alloc_pidmap can be found at [link](http://lxr.linux.no/linux-bk+v2.6.11/kernel/pid.c#L35)

Comment: From what I know, the operating system specification for most OS-es (including Linux) states that you should not assume anything about PID values. The way they are allocated can change in future versions of that particular OS (or may be incompatible with previous versions). If PIDs are important for your application, get them EXPLICITLY and without any assumption about the range in which they're in.

Comment: After more code reading and listing the real daemon processes in Linux, I found my assumption about daemon's pid < 300 was incorrect. The pid will be used from 0 to max; just in the beginning, a lot of daemons will be forked, and low values will be allocated to them, which gave me the wrong impression. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Apart from kernel processes (strange beasts like `kauditd`) and from the very first `init` every process was created by `fork` (even "daemon" ones, like `sendmail` or `lpd`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK pid are allocated by the kernel; the limit of 300 (i.e. `#define RESERVED_PIDS   300` private inside `kernel/pid.c`) you are seeing is perhaps because on most systems, several processes have been forked early in the bootstrap (e.g. from `initrd` perhaps).

You could test by booting from GRUB directly into a kernel with `init=/bin/sh`

Some processes are kernel processes (without userland code, e.g. `kworker` or `kauditd`), which are not started by fork from init or descendants. They are probably started with `kthread_create` *inside* the kernel (and without any syscall).

And you should explain why are you asking that. Is your question about determining if a process is a deamon or not?